# Erro 500 $.post CodeIgniter no Servidor

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Boa tarde pessoal,

estou com um problema o dia todo e não consigo resolver, eu tenho um sistema e ele funciona no servidor localhost perfeitamente, mas no servidor algumas funções ajax nao conseguem enviar o post.
Tem algo muito estranho que é o seguinte, se eu dar um echo na função e retirar o php ele devolve normalmente o retorno mas com a função ele não funciona.

Segue a função em ajax e a função que recebe no codeigniter.

http://pastebin.com/ABYLBPr8

Obrigado

Comment: Vocês não vao acreditar mas era a letra da classe que estava minuscula.

Answer (score 0):

Se voce clicar nos detalhes da Requisição Ajax, não retorna nenhuma informação?
Normalmente o CI apresenta o erro,

Comment: Consegui resolver amigo, não estava dando nenhum informação pelo erro, eu tinha colocado a primeira letra da classe em minusculo, no localhost funcionava mas no servidor dava pau.